# SQL Server Express : Reporting Services.. limitations on charts?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-express

If you look the [Edition Comparison](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx)...

It says for `Express Edition` that this option is not enabled for `SQL Server Express`..

**Enhanced Gauges and Charting**

Anyone know what the limitations are on this item? I can't seem to find any more information..

Many thanks,

Brett

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correct, the prettier graphs and charts that came with including Dundas Charts in SSRS aren't included in the Express edition.